# how to select unmached rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
create table user_info(
    userID int,
    names varchar(20),
    fatherName varchar(20),
    grade varchar(10),
    status varchar(20)
)

insert into user_info values(001,'raj singh','venkatesh','A','active')
insert into user_info values(008,'atal bihari','ram pratap','c','departed') 
insert into user_info values(005,'sultaan mirja','jai khan','b','active')
insert into user_info values(009,'faiz ali','mahboob ali','d','termineted')
insert into user_info values(003,'david sam','david rk','A','awarded')

userID  names           fatherName     grade   status
----------------------------------------------------
001     raj singh       venkatesh      A       active
008     atal bihari     ram pratap     c       departed
005     sultaan mirja   jai khan       b       active 
009     faiz ali        mahboob ali    d       termineted 
003     david sam       david rk       A       awarded
```

The second table:

```
create table user_contact(
    userID int,
    contectNo int,
    houseNo varchar(20),
    city varchar(20),
    grade varchar(10)
)

insert into user_contact values(001,'2586931475','384 b block','ludhiyan','A')
insert into user_contact values(005,'9817588937','786 sector 4','lahore','b')
insert into user_contact values(0010,'8081829973','164 p.road','kanpur','A')
insert into user_contact values(0011,'7898654532','132 ram janki puram','ayodhya','c')
insert into user_contact values(009,'8978231254','420 coco-cola','limka','e')

userID    contectNo      houseNo               city            grade  
--------------------------------------------------------------------
001       2586931475     384 b block           ludhiyan        A 
005       9817588937     786 sector 4          lahore          b 
0010      8081829973     164 p.road            kanpur          A 
0011      7898654532     132 ram janki puram   ayodhya         c 
009       8978231254     420 coco-cola         limka           e
```

I want to result:

```
names           fatherName          contectNo             city 
------------------------------------------------------------------
atal bihari     ram pratap          null                  null
david sam       david rk            null                  null        
null            null                8081829973            kanpur  
null            null                7898654532            ayodhya
```

Comment: What hace you tried so far?

Comment: You should have a foreign key that prevents having user contact for users that do not exist.

Comment: can i do this without primary and foreign key ....sir @JamesZ

Comment: Do what? To have a proper database design you should have both primary and foreign keys to ensure referential integrity, so you won't end up in a situation where you have addresses without users.

Comment: thanku sir...@JamesZ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT ui.names,
       ui.fathername,
       uc.contectNo,
       uc.city
FROM   user_contact uc
       FULL OUTER JOIN user_info ui
                    ON uc.userID = ui.userID
WHERE  ui.userID IS NULL
        OR uc.userID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

FIRST, couple of things:

1. you can not store `string` when you are declaring `int`.
2. Try Using AUTO INCREMENTED PKs as IDs instead of 001 or 002(*even, these will be stored as 1 and 2 only as type is int*).

**SOLUTION:**
Use `FULL OUTER JOIN` .

The idea behind `FULL OUTER JOIN` is, you want to do a product keeping each and every row regardless of their presence in both the tables.

Check [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef592/2).